# One condition multiple rules .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to redirect my old domain to new domain if request has specific word.

EX:

If request has keyword **new**

```
http://www.example.com/new/abc
```

It will redirects to

```
http://www.newexample.com/abc
```

remove **new** from url and redirect to new domain

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} new
RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```